# CSS when applied to specific DIV misses some details

Tags: html, css

I have a strange situation when attempting to apply certain styles to a specific div. Here is the code:

```
    <style>
        div#West_Pane {
            ul {
                animation-duration: 4s;
                padding-left: 20px;
            }
            ul li {
                display: block ;
                cursor:pointer;
                animation-duration: 4s;
                font-size: 12px;
                clear: both;
                -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Prevent selection on double click for Chrome/Safari  */        
                -moz-user-select: none;     /* Prevent selection on double click for Firefox        */
                -ms-user-select: none;      /* Prevent selection on double click for IE10+          */
            }

            li.groupCollapsed:before {
                content: "\e080";
                font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
                font-size: 12px;
                float: left;
                margin-top: 4px;
                margin-left: -17px;
                color: blue;
            }

            li.groupExpanded:before {
                content: "\e114";
                font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
                font-size: 12px;
                float: left;
                margin-top: 4px;
                margin-left: -17px;
                color: blue;
            }
        }
    </style>
<div id="West_Pane" ng-controller="Main_Commands_List_Controller" style="background:#f9ebea;">
    <compile-Directive id="cmpldirective" content="Commands_Tree_Contents_LTR"></compile-Directive>
</div>
```

The contents of the `West_Pane` is a generated multi-level menu. It works OK so I'm not showing the JavaScript.

If I comment out the `div#West_Pane{...}` wrapping, it all looks as needed for the menu but other things within the same page are negatively affected.

When I uncomment it, two things happens:

1. The `cursor:pointer` element (see settings for `ul il`) appears to be ignored,
2. The Glyphicons set for the classes `groupCollapsed:before` and `groupExpanded:before` are not shown (in fact, when checking the `before` contents within the browser there is nothing defined, not even the **before** part of the element).

Comment: Check your West_pane id not being called multiple times on page.. and your code is in less not in css..

Comment: Thank you @SahilDhir for your reply. I re-checked and the string `West_Pane` appears only twice in the page, once as ID of the div, and the other as a reference in the style block. What I don't understand is why the wrapping `div#West_Pane` has this strange effect (note that other properties appear to be working OK).

Comment: if you can share your code that will be a help. As seeing only this its difficult to answer..

Comment: As stated, the code generating the contents of the lists works OK since, when removing the `div#West_Pane` wrapping for the style, things are displayed OK. There is a `before::` entry in the markup (showing the element in Chrome), but this is missing with the wrapping. This makes me think that the issue is with the wrapping and not with the JS code generating the lists.

Comment: Basically the problem is with the structure of code.. So I have to see the structure as how it is render on the page. So without seeing the ouput I can't really say whats happening :)

Comment: Well.... I see if I can share the code (not sure I'm allowed to though). Thanks for the time being. Will buzz you here if I add the code.

Comment: Pseudo elements should be prefixed with two colons `::before`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue by try-and-error but not after getting a clear understanding.
There were two changes needed to obtain the desired result:

1. DELETE blanks that were separating elements in a css specification, like:

   ```
    .class > li + li {...}
   ```

   should be:

   ```
    .class>li+li {...}
   ```
2. The issue was that the pills of a multi-tabs div were being shown one UNDER the other instead AFTER the other. I resolved this by setting a small class definition for those pills and setting `float:none;`.

Comment: Delete space in that CSS rule won't make any difference. They work just fine both, and by that won't be to any use for other users

Comment: @LGSon, you may be right, but the above changes were what made things work (and nothing else). I have no explanation about why though.

Comment: Please refrain from adding "hope this helps" to your answers. All answers, bar troublemaking and trolling, are posted with the hope that it helps, and thus the phrase is redundant.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.